# with statement work on class

Tags: python, with-statement

```
{class foo(object):
    def __enter__ (self):
        print("Enter")
    def __exit__(self,type,value,traceback):
        print("Exit")
    def method(self):
        print("Method")
with foo() as instant:
    instant.method()}
```

Execute this py file and console shows these message:

```
Enter
Exit

instant.method()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'method'
```

unable to find methods?

Comment: what is the enclosing `{}` for? Also, should it not be `new foo()` for a class instance ?

Comment: @karthikr: Python constructors are invoked as functions, no `new`.

Answer (score 11):

`__enter__` should return `self`:

```
class foo(object):
    def __enter__ (self):
        print("Enter")
        return self
    def __exit__(self,type,value,traceback):
        print("Exit")
    def method(self):
        print("Method")
with foo() as instant:
    instant.method()
```

yields

```
Enter
Method
Exit
```

If `__enter__` does not return `self`, then it returns `None` by default. Thus, `instant` is assigned the value `None`. This is why you get the error message

> '**NoneType**' object has no attribute 'method'

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your `__enter__` method does not return `self`.